# Invalid shipping method, WooCommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am stuck with a issue and am not being able to solve it. I did check the other questions and did other research but I didn't find proper answers this.

When shipping is enabled and I try to checkout, I get **Invalid shipping method** error. When I disable the shipping and then checkout, it works properly. I have to enable the shipping make it work.

Can anyone suggest anything on this issue? Please

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

May be you have just enabled the 'Enable shipping' from shipping options page(`Woocommerce -> Settings -> Shipping` ). You need to enable the Shipping Methods also. For enabling shipping methods click on shipping method name from shipping methods table displayed on shipping options page. Check the checkbox ' Enable this shipping method ' and save the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that we have to enable from shipping methods too.